# jQuery field validation not working

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I want to validate user input when the user clicked on the submit button, but it won't work.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function validateForm() {
      if ($('#u').value() == '') 
      {
         alert("no value found");
         return false;
      }

  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" action="main.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="u" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: There's no `id="u"` in your form.

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't work"?

Comment: just `$('#u').val()` . And you'll get it

Comment: if  script is fine then try to replace  $ with jQuery  many time there  is possible confliction with jQuery

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems in your code.

- The value is **not** a `function` but `attribute` remove you can use `val()` and also you can not use value with jQuery object you can use it with DOM object.
- You have probably forgot to assign id to your input field also assign that.
- The statement `<input type="text">` should b4 `<input id="u" type="text">`
- You have extra parenthesis after closes currly bracket of function validateForm, you are   not closing input tags.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MjDze/2/)**

```
if ($('#u').val() == '') 
{
   alert("no value found");
   return false;
}
```

You can use native javascript method getElementById to get the DOM element (object) and use value property of that object.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MjDze/3/)**

```
if (document.getElementById('u').value == '') 
{
     alert("no value found");
     return false;
}
```

Comment: True, but there is no id="u", so your answer doesn't work for his particular problem. EDIT: Now the question includes id="u", he just modified it. Lol.

Comment: I want to change the value of #label instead of alert. Thats why i used jquery

Comment: You can do that with javascript as well, as for as I know, I could not see any label in your html

Comment: Check my updated demo with both jQuery and javascript with changing label instead of alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($('#u').value() == '') 
{
    alert("no value found");
    return false;
} else {
    $('form[name="myForm"]').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar suggested check your existing code for the missing id. I would add the `id="u"` to the `<input type="text">` and also be careful in choosing id names that are ambiguous especially so that others could read your code later.

*Now that you've edited the original question it is hard to see how my answer appears relevant*

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I found an awkwardness in your code. Let's focus to this line :

```
  ......
   if ($('#u').value() == '') 
   {
     alert("no value found");
     return false;
   }

});

});
```

There's two `});`, which one for `$(document)` and which one for `if()` ?? Although for `if()`, don't type like that, just `}` for conditional closing. And for make a `function ...`, you don't need to put function inside `$(document).ready`. It can stand-alone. For example :

```
function validateForm() {

   if ($('#u').val() == '') 
   {
      alert("no value found");
      return false;
   }

}
```

**And you should change .value() to .val()**

[See this](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/4dWR5/) for the result. Hope this helps